# are random rotations dense?

Tags: probability

Let $(X_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ a i.i.d. sequence of random variables such that $X_i$ is absolutely continuous.

Is it true that the set of points $$\left\lbrace\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \mod 1 \quad \bigg\vert \quad n \in \mathbb{N}\right\rbrace$$
is dense in $[0,1)$ a.e ?

I came up with this problem just for fun and I don't know how to solve it.

Any help or idea will be appreciated.

Comment: You have written down a random set. Are you asking whether it is *almost surely* dense in $[0,1)$?

Comment: exactly, thanks!